# ViewPager within a DialogFragment does not change tabs onClick

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-dialogfragment, android-nested-fragment

I have created a popup DialogFragment with a ViewPager containing 3 tabs.
I am able to swipe between these tabs, although I also want to be able to click on the tab headers to change between these tabs. Does anybody know if this is possible?

I have read that this is doable with the action bar layout, however since it is a popup dialog this isn't possible for me.

Here is my code:

The ViewPager Adapter:

```
public class TabAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

  public TabAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
    super(fragmentManager);
  }

  @Override
  public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
      case 0:
        return new Tab1();
      case 1:
        return new Tab2();
      case 2:
        return new Tab3();
      default:
        return null;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return 3;
  }

  @Override
  public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    switch (position) {
      case 0:
        return "First Tab";
      case 1:
        return "Second Tab";
      case 2:
        return "Third Tab";
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

The DialogFragment:

```
public class TabFragment extends DialogFragment {
  @Override
  public Dialog onCreateDialog(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.getWindow() .setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    return dialog;
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tablayoutfragment, container);
    TabAdapter tabAdapter = new TabAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(tabAdapter);

    return view;
  }

}
```

Each of the tabs just contain a text view currently, nothing exciting there.
Please let me know if you see anything that I have missed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do this! You don't need to use the ActionBar to have these tabs. Use a [PagerTitleStrip](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#PagerTitleStrip) instead of the ActionBar tabs and implement it exactly as described in the rest of the linked article.

Edit:

Alternatively you could use [ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator), developed by Jake Wharton. The usage would be the same as the linked article too.

Comment: You lead me to the correct answer : I was using a PagerTitleStrip but needed to use the PagerTabStrip instead.